# Incorrect number of parameters passed to subroutine

Tags: raku

In perl6 I define a subroutine with two parameters, one a scalar and the other an array. When I call the subroutine I receive a run-time error saying that only one parameter was passed when two were expected.

I have tried redefining the subroutine with only one parameter, once for each parameter type, and these cases succeed.

```
my  @bb="red", "orange", "yellow", "green", "bleu", "indigo", "violet";

sub1(@bb,123);

sub sub1(@val2, $v) {
    print "\@val2 = @val2\n"; 
    print "\$v = $v\n"; 
}
```

I expect the output to be:
red orange yellow green blue indigo violet
123

The actual result is:
Too few positionals passed; expected 2 arguments but got 1

Comment: It works for me. Ubuntu 19.04, rakudo 2019.03. Note that to interpolate `@val2` inside double quotes you should use the Zen slice `@val2[]`, see [String Interpolation and the Zen Slice](https://perl6advent.wordpress.com/2014/12/13/day-13-string-interpolation-and-the-zen-slice)

Comment: Indeed, this feels like per-GLR behaviour, which would indicate a very old perl6.

Comment: The version is  v2019.03.1

Comment: @odbux. Just spotted your version comment. No official Rakudo should produce the error you've shown for the code you've shown. Here's [repl.it running your code followed by a statement printing system info](https://repl.it/repls/GlisteningDeeppinkFormat). At the time of writing this repl.it is running the same version you report. Perhaps your Rakudo is using an experimental backend? If you'd like to help us solve this riddle, please copy the code in the repl.it I've linked, run it with your Rakudo, and paste a link to a copy of the output using a pastebin service (eg gist.github.com). TIA.